# Getting a linting error from creating an HTTPStatus object

Tags: python, http, pylint

I'm trying to get HTTP Status phrases from the `http.HTTPStatus` in my code, so basically I'm doing the following:

```
http.HTTPStatus(code).phrase
```

It works fine, but when I run pylint on my code, it fails with error:

```
E: 60,14: No value for argument 'phrase' in constructor call (no-value-for-parameter)
```

`http.HTTPStatus` (from Python source) class looks like the following:

```
class HTTPStatus(IntEnum):
"""HTTP status codes and reason phrases

Status codes from the following RFCs are all observed:

    * RFC 7231: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1), obsoletes 2616
    * RFC 6585: Additional HTTP Status Codes
    * RFC 3229: Delta encoding in HTTP
    * RFC 4918: HTTP Extensions for WebDAV, obsoletes 2518
    * RFC 5842: Binding Extensions to WebDAV
    * RFC 7238: Permanent Redirect
    * RFC 2295: Transparent Content Negotiation in HTTP
    * RFC 2774: An HTTP Extension Framework
"""
def __new__(cls, value, phrase, description=''):
    obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
    obj._value_ = value

    obj.phrase = phrase
    obj.description = description
    return obj
...
```

Any tips on that?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should report this to pylint at https://github.com/pycqa/pylint, as it seems to be a bug with it.

Comment: @ELCapitaine were you able to get more info on this pylint error or report this to pylint or http?